# Android Studio Commit&Push bug

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio, intellij-idea

Sometimes I can't commit and push changed files on Github via Android Studio. I'm pressing "Commit changes" button (Ctrl + K), there appears window with changed files, then I'm pressing "Commit and Push..." button, then I can see progress bar of files committing (but sometimes even this window doesn't appear) and then progress bar hiding and Push window doesn't appear. If I press "Commit and Push..." button again it will repeat all this stuff, but window where I can choose the remote to push my commit doesn't appear. I have several Android projects on one branch and I'm changing them at the same time (per one commit). Sometimes it helps to try to commit and push from another project opened in another instance of Android Studio. But not this time. I can't work without git and this is very frustrating, so please help me with advice, thanks!

Comment: try to use command line tool

Comment: https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

Comment: Same problem with subversion.... and same workaround as suggested by n1ck. Thks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Unchecked "Perform code analysis" in "Commit Changes" window and it's worked! It seems like Android Studio can't understand some files and rejects it...

Comment: Spend 3 hours on this. TY. But why it happen?

Comment: The strange thing is that Android Studio does not show any error message. Clicking on the commit button shows the code analysis progress bar and after the bar disappears nothing happens and the commit window does not disappear. Clicking a second time does not even show the code analysis progress bar.

Comment: You just made my night. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I have wasted a lot time on that.

Comment: Thanks! Great advice!

Comment: Thanks - I have created bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203111&can=4&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: Thanks !! Working nice !!

Comment: Year 2019, still keeps happening.